# Where am I going wrong in Bresenham circle drawing algorithm?

Tags: bresenham

Well, this sounds ridiculous but its now more than ten times I am trying to see what I am doing wrong in this example. I have seen the tutorial on the web, and the example is shown below:

[image]

At stage **3**: Are we not supposed to decrement `Yi` to 9? I am saying this because the decision variable `Pi=13` satisfying the condition that `if Pi>=0, Yi +1=Yi-1` as shown below:[image]

**Question:** Where am I going wrong? Please, someone explain this to me.

**PS:** I appreciate even more worked examples, thanks.

Comment: When having troubles in understanding iterations, it's useful to 1) write the iterations by hand and 2) to write the iterations with the values. ( ` if p0 < 0 then { y1 = y0;  p1 = p0 + 4*x0 + 6 ; } else if p0 >=0 { y1 = y0 -1; p1 = ... .... ` )
Write until you get it !!! :-)

Comment: Thanks, it is what I been doing but was lost as to which `Pi` determines which coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,
We are not supposed to decrement value of `Yi` to 9 at 3rd Stage.
Let me elaborate you where you are going wrong,

- Consider you are at 3rd Stage.
- Now you are checking value of `Pi` **based on previous value of itself** that is from 2nd stage.
- Here you will do,  `Pi = -1 + 4(2) + 6`
- The value 13 will be obtained **after** performing this operation at this stage.
- After this value is obtained, at 4th stage, you'll check value of `Pi` from 3rd stage.
- Now `Pi` will be greater than 0 and hence `Yi` will decrement to 9.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mean `Pi` from `2nd stage` determines the coordinates **(x,y)** of 3rd stage`, Pi from 3rd determines coordinates of 4th stage,...? Like we first calculate the coordinates of stage 3 based on the value of Pi form 2nd stage before we calculate Pi of stage 3?

Comment: Yes. Exactly! Try doing it on paper for more precise understanding.

Comment: Well, thanks, I been doing it on paper and its now making sense.